# Find the altitude of an irregular tetrahedron given all 4 vertex positions

Tags: math, vector, unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

I have an irregular tetrahedron using 4 vertices.

I need to find out the altitude given that one specific vertex is the top and the others are the base.

Basically the height would be the shortest distance from the top to its base creating a 90 degrees angle. It should be a simple math question but I cannot find anything on Google.

I am looking for an optimized function that looks like this :

```
float GetPyramidAltitude (Vector3 top, Vector3 baseA, Vector3 baseB, Vector3 baseC) {
     ...
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, however I found a solution from a method in Unity.

Basically we only need 3 parameters : the top vertex, one vertex from the base and the base's face normal which I already had.

Here's my solution :

```
float GetPyramidAltitude (Vector3 top, Vector3 baseA, Vector3 baseNormal) {
    Vector3 topToBase = Vector3.Project(baseA - top, baseNormal);
    return topToBase.magnitude;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to finding the distance between a point and a plane.  The plane is defined by the three points comprising the base.  There is a detailed explanation on [determining a plane given three points](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html) and [finding the minimal distance between a point and a plane](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html).

Disclaimer:  I don't know Unity3D, so I'm kind of making up the syntax below.  If something's not clear, let me know; otherwise you're going to have to translate into something that will compile using the Unity3D API.

The first step is to determine the equation of the plane given three points.  The plane normal is given by:

```
n = cross(baseB-baseA, baseC-baseA);
n = n / norm(n);
```

Where `cross` returns the cross product of the two arguments, and `norm` returns the l2 norm (vector magnitude).  The offset term in the plane equation is given by:

```
d = -n.x*baseA.x - n.y*baseA.y - n.z*baseA.z;
```

This will result in the plane equation:

```
n.x*X + n.y*Y + n.z*Z + d = 0
```

To find the distance between the `top` and the plane is then given by

```
D = dot(n, top) + d;
```

where `dot` is the dot product of the unit vector normal of the plane `n` and `top` and d is defined earlier.  When `D > 0` `top` is "above" the plane defined by the three base points where the normal points "up".  When `D < 0` the `top` is below the plane.  So, in your case, you may want to take the absolute value of `D` to get the distance.